# Adding protobuff-net serialization to WCF through code with knowntypes

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

I currently have all of my WCF connections defined in code and I'm trying to shoehorn protobuff-net serialization in with little success. None of my contracts are marked with the knowntype attribute as we have a base message with a payload (it would be dozens of knowntypes). We figure out the knowntypes we have and cache them in a class derived from DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior. Then in the overridden CreateSerializer function I pass the cached known types into the DataContractSerializer as follows

```
 public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns,   IList<Type> knownTypes)
 {
          new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, m_Known ?? knownTypes, 0x7FFF, ...)
 }
```

Is there some way to pass a list of known types to the protobuf-net serializer. I realize protobuf-net isn't meant to mirror the serializers for WCF, but it would be nice if they followed the pattern for allowing overriding the knowntypes list. Thanks for any help.

However I don't have the option to treat the Protobuf-net serializer this way (I looked at the ProtoOperationBehavior). Is there anyway to not have known types specified in the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "v2", the available subtypes can be defined (against a RuntimeTypeModel) on the fly at runtime via `.AddSubType(...)` (in fact, all the attributes now only serve as a default configuration for the type-model, which can be configured any which way).

However, I should stress that v2 is currently in ***beta***, and as [noted in the blog](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/05/protobuf-net-v2-beta.html) the WCF hooks are currently not included in the beta, purely while I finish validation etc. However, I expect that with your setup as shown in the question it should be trivial (it will merely be a case of passing the model into the `XmlObjectSerializer` implementation provided).

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the speedy reply. I've downloaded the current depot and at least with the current code I think I'm going to have some issues (I'm not sure if this is what v2 in downloads is based on). I can't create the serializer myself as XmlProtoSerializer is private to the assembly (you access it via reflection), and I can't derive from ProtoOperationBehavior as its internal and sealed. If either one of those things were false I would be able to drop this in, but I'm having trouble figuring out how it would work.

Comment: @Steve - yes, and that ties into the whole "while I finish validation" ;p It does indeed sound like making the XmlProtoSerializer public (with a constructor taking the type-model) is the most pragmatic option. I very much want to be happy that the WCF story is good, which is why *in the first drop of the beta* the WCF hooks aren't officially announced. I can probably include the XmlProtoSerializer stuff in the next drop

Comment: @Marc, haha I didn't get exactly what you meant by hooks. sorry. If I can make one small feature request, it would be nice to be able to turn on the preserve object references in the constructor, that was a very inconvenient feature to track down in the WCF documentation. Out of curiosity, is it expensive to turn that feature on by default? Thanks for all of the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Steve the main problem there is that it then takes me a *long* way from anything even remotely portable between platforms. For an unrelated issue, I was toying with adding a "this type should always be treated as a reference" - would that suffice?

Comment: @Marc - yes, that would work. I only suggested it because it took me more than a day to track down an error in my datacontract. I had a generic tree structure where each node has a reference to the parent that was not getting serialized by WCF. The worst part was the WCF tracing was particularly unhelpful. Finally, I got a channel fault that had the particular error message about deserializing references. For how difficult of an error it is to track down I would have thought MS would have made it default unless it was really expensive. I believe MS has a "type as a reference" attributd also

Comment: @Steve - well, personally I'd rather steer people towards structuring their DTO such that it works as a tree ;p But I know where you are coming from...